# How do I decrypt (using RSA) in openssl with a binary private key file?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, key, rsa

I have a binary key file `privkey.bin` but can't seem to either

- convert it to a .pem file for use in openssl (it says "cannot load private key")
- use it in openssl to decrypt the message directly (same error)

Any help would help and be appreciated.

Comment: The name of the file contains very little in the way of hints as to its contents. There are multiple incompatible formats for private keys and nothing in your question helps identify which is the correct one.

Comment: I think it's in the DER format, in which case I want to convert DER to PEM. I tried using openssl to do that but it still gave me an error

Comment: There are still at least five different commonly used possibilities that may be DER-encoded: PKCS#1 private key (encrypted or not), PKCS#8 (encrypted or not), and PKCS#12. You have to know which one. You can try all three with the appropriate openssl command and see if one of them works. Also, openssl works just fine with DER files.